# How import via IMPORTXML text value of "/a" only if "/a/@href" exists?

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Current formula:
`IMPORTXML("https://int.soccerway.com/international/europe/uefa-champions-league/20192020/s17689/final-stages/","//td[@class='team team-a'] | //td[@class='team team-a strong']/a")`

How import values of `//td[@class='team team-a']` and `//td[@class='team team-a strong']/a` only `//td[@class='team team-a']/@href` and `//td[@class='team team-a strong']/a/@href` values exist?

Example:
[image]

`Winner Semi-final 2` and `Winner Semi-final 1` **not contains links /@href**

`RB Leipzig` **contains link /@href** - https://int.soccerway.com/teams/germany/rb-leipzig/13410/
`PSG` **contains link /@href** - https://int.soccerway.com/teams/france/paris-saint-germain-fc/886/

The result of the import I want would be this:

> RB Leipzig
> PSG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this should help:

```
=IMPORTXML(url,"//h2[span='Semi-finals']/following-sibling::div[@class='content']//td[contains(@class,'team')]/a[@href]")
```

Output:

```
RB Leipzig
PSG
```